# Finiding the integral [0,1] of an interesting function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been working in this problem for 4 days, and I just can't get anywhere, so here it is:

Be f the function with domain [0,1], defined in the following way:

for every x between 0 and 1, we have the decimal expansion, the infinite succession of their digits

[; x = 0,a_1 a_2 a_3 ....... ;]

We assume that this expansion does not have an infinite succession of 9, that is we use 0.15000000...... instead of 0.1499999999999999.....

Now we will define f as:

if the decimal expansion starts with:

[; x = 0, a_1 a_2 .... a_n 9... ;]

then

[; f(x) = 0, a_1 a_2 a_3.... a_n 9. ;]

if the decimal expansion of x does not have any 9, then:

[; f(x) = 0 ;]

i.e x = 1/4 then  f(x) = 0, x = pi/10  then f(x)=0,314159

Using the definitions of lower and upper sums, find the integral from 0 to 1 of f. Or show that doesn't exist.

My work:

My first thought was that f is not integrable, my solution to the problem was to show that, it doesn't matter how we make the partition [0,1], there is always going to be a number on that subinterval on which f(x) = 0 (that being said a number on which the decimal expansion does not have a 9) and an x such that f(x) > 0 (that being said a number on which the decimal expansion does  have a 9). So 
The Upper Sums and the lower sums will never be equal but I do not know how to prove that. Help?

I tried also sandwich somehow, but I arrived at

[; 0< \int_0 ^1 (f(x))<8/9 ;]

but that doesn't tell me anything since f(x) approx. g(x)=x, then the integral should be less than 1/2

Also, my professor suggested that f is integrable and the hint was, that at some point we will have to use infinite geometric sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this. Let $E_1 = [0.9,1]$. Then $f= 0.9$ on $E_1$. Then consider 
$E_2 = [0.09, 0.1] \cup\cdots \cup [0.89. 0.9]$. Then $f$ is constant on each intervals. Inductively you can calculate the integral of each $f_1, f_2$ and $f_n$ is monotone increasing to $f$. Thus you can find the integral of $f$.

Comment: Yes, that's a beutiful insight, thank you.